# Multisort flag doesn't seem to work

Tags: array, multisort

The multisort flag for arrays doesn't work the way I'm trying it. This is how I'm using it.

`{% for conv in conversations|multisort(['postDate'],['SORT_DESC']) %}`

This is the error I keep getting.

**array_multisort(): Argument #2 is expected to be an array or a sort flag**

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change `['SORT_DESC']` to `[SORT_DESC]`. See [this tweet](https://twitter.com/nystudio107/status/1020719464147570688) for an example. `SORT_DESC` is a PHP constant, not a string.